# Как принять POST запрос?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Как принять POST запрос?

Не понимаю как это сделать, нигде не нашёл.

Например, нам отсылают данные  с помощью API (передают ФИО и номер телефона), а как нам их принять, не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Например, https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: @Bakhuss если оформите ответ, то я отмечу его как правильным.

Comment: Благодарю, но там только ссылка на гайд, которая гуглится на раз. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала необходим UserRepo (необходим, чтобы программа понимала куда отправлять и с чем работает)

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Дальше Application (запуск нашего Spring)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserController (программа принимает и отправляет на преобразование данных вида Json)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users") //какое угодно слово может быть вместо users
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {
        userRepo.save(requestUserDetails);
        return "Сообщение доставлено.";
    }
}
```

В заключении User (преобразовывает данные)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "НАЗВАНИЕ БД", schema = "НАЗВАНИЕ СХЕМЫ")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String phone;

    private String message;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setLastName(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```